# Reasoning behind "x = x or some_constant" in google style

Tags: python, docstring

In [google's pydoc styleguide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md) I stumbled upon 2.14.4

Yes:

```
 ...
 def f(x=None):
     if x is None:
         x = []
```

No:

```
 ...
 def f(x=None):
     x = x or []
```

I wonder, why if statement is preferred over `x = x or []`? Is there some deeper meaning behind this?

Comment: It's a style guide, so generally readability is a focus. Also note these two examples aren't semantically equivalent, exactly, but probably close enough in reality

Comment: I do not think this question is a duplicate (especially with regard to explanation of google style docs). I asked for the reasoning and Bill Shubert *actually* provided a simple and clear answer that I was not aware of. The linked duplicate post don't even go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If x is false (the boolean value), then it will be replaced with []. Usually you only want to replace when it is actually None.

Comment: If x is *fasley*; empty strings, `0`, etc.. would also apply to this

Comment: This function is presumably meant to accept a list, so the problem is when you pass an empty list it doesn't retain a reference to the actual empty list that is passed; this means any mutations won't be made to the argument, which is different behaviour to when the argument is a non-empty list.

Comment: More exactly if x is falsey which means x is something for which "bool(x) == False".